# Search widget addTextChangedListner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-search

I have implemented my **listview Filtering using edit text box using below code**..
I was wondering how to implement exact **Filtering using search widget On Action Bar**. AFAIK search widget don't have any addTextChangedListener..

I have gone through android developers for search widget and couldn't find any way to do What I am trying To achieve.

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           // When user changed the Text
           MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
}
```